# Conditional Formatting (Color) of cells on a sheet based on values on another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to achieve conditional formatting but Unable to sort out a system.
Things i am trying to achieve:

1. Match Styles and Pattern column in both sheets. Range: A21: B40 with A2: C63.
2. Upon Match, Column headers ( G1 : AO1 ) in Order Sheet would be matched with the Guide Sheet Row Values A21: B40, where color of cell would change according to the guide sheet in the order sheet. If any column headers dont match then it would stay white.

I have attached an example sheet where the ST5 in the order sheet was used as example but manually. If the process could be made automatic it would ease my work in office.

Example Sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cTgAKhIO0_OJgoReuAMSaZU-7BE4P2xHdt3ASsPgIH0/edit?usp=sharing

I am also willing to do a Hangouts call to sort these system.

Sorry for the incapability to explain clearly and Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Guide you will need 4 rules. Add in cell C21. This will color code Guide.

Apply to Range C21:R1017 (for all 4 rules)

Custom Formula

```
=match(C21,$C$2:$C$10,0)

=match(C21,$E$2:$E$16,0)

=match(C21,$G$2:$G$9,0)

=match(C21,$I$2:$I$4,0)
```

For Orders, you need script. Try the following:

```
function colorCells(){
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
 var s=ss.getSheetByName("Orders")
 var s1=ss.getSheetByName("Guide")
 var lr=s.getLastRow()
 var lc=s.getLastColumn()
 var lr1=s1.getLastRow()
 var lc1=s1.getLastColumn()
 var orderdata=s.getRange(1, 1, lr, lc).getValues()
 var guidedata=s1.getRange(21, 1, lr1=21, lc1).getValues()
 var headers=s.getRange(1, 7, 1, lc-6).getValues()
 for(var i=0;i<orderdata.length;i++){
   for(var j=0;j<guidedata.length;j++){
     if(orderdata[i][1]==guidedata[j][0] && orderdata[i][2]==guidedata[j][1]){
         var row=i+1
         var row1=j+21
         var line=s1.getRange(row1, 3, 1,18).getBackgrounds()
         var lval=s1.getRange(row1, 3, 1,18).getValues()
      for(var k=0;k<headers[0].length;k++){
         for(var l=0;l<lval[0].length;l++){
          var t=headers[0][k]
          var t1=lval[0][l]
          if(t==t1){
             var c=s1.getRange(row1, l+3, 1,1).getBackground()
             var sc=s.getRange(row, k+7, 1,1).setBackground(c)
      }}}}}}}
```

This is a working sample of your spreadsheet. Make a copy and try it:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12KoRLAnkJwQB0OKTmauxmqxq5BT71gyIgCo3Wf-jemk/edit?usp=sharing